# Is it common to bind default values in 'CREATE TABLE' statements?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, prepared-statement

Should I exec directly (pseudo code)...

```
q = "CREATE TABLE `usermood` { `id` INT, `name` TEXT, `mood` VARCHAR DEFAULT 'gloomy' }";
exec(q);
```

...or bind to a (un)named placeholder?

```
q = "CREATE TABLE `usermood` { `id` INT, `name` TEXT, `mood` VARCHAR DEFAULT :mood }";
prepare(q);
bind(q, ":mood", 'gloomy');
exec(q);
```

I've never seen it in any example code.

It's less about the security of escaping (because I control the create statements) but rather about converting the value into a database compatible format (automatic selection of content representation by type).

I'm using MySQL as well as SQLite3.

Are there database drivers that don't support binding in create statements?

If anyone is interested: I'm using `QSqlQuery` with `QVariant` as value.

Comment: If this is canned code and there is no possibility of this statement ever being touched by user input, then the non-binding version seems completely appropriate. I don't think there would be any advantages in any RDBMS for 'type determination' with binding. It's sort of a wash.

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for a default value. I didn't find anything about that in the docs - But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use parameter binding when:

- You are using a value from an unknown source, and you want to protect against SQL injection.
- You want to prepare a statement and execute it repeatedly using different values for the parameter.

Neither of these is likely for your CREATE TABLE example.

I have never used a parameter in any DDL statement.

P.S.: You can't set a DEFAULT for a TEXT column regardless of whether it's a bound parameter or a literal value in the DDL statement, but I'm guessing your example above is artificial.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I changed `TEXT` to `VARCHAR` in the question to prevent confusing future readers.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite explicitly forbids binding default values:

[from the SQLite docs:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

> An explicit DEFAULT clause may specify that the default value is NULL, a string constant, a blob constant, a signed-number, **or any constant expression** enclosed in parentheses. A default value may also be one of the special case-independent keywords CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. For the purposes of the DEFAULT clause, **an expression is considered constant if it does contains no** sub-queries, column or table references, **bound parameters**, or string literals enclosed in double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

(emphasis by me)